# MySQL Database Replication and Server Load

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, database-replication

I have an online service with around 5000 MySQL databases. Now, I am interested in building a development area of the exactly same environment in my office, therefore, I am about to setup MySQL replication between my live MySQL server and development MySQL server.

But my concern is the load which will occur on my live MySQL server once replication is started. Do you have any experience? Will this process cause extra load on my production server?

Thanks, have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning on binary logging (for replication) can severely affect performance.  It calls fsync to ensure consistency, so everything is slower.  A few articles to read:

1. http://jcole.us/blog/archives/2006/05/25/on-disk-performance-and-mysql-replication/
2. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/27/jeremy-cole-on-mysql-replication/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I decided not to go with replication :(